# How to add 2nd (circular) histogram reading from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, histogram

I am new to python and have cobbled together some code that reads from the first index of .csv file (containing values in radians) and plots both a histogram and circular histogram. I would like to add a second (circular) histogram that reads from the 2nd index. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('radians.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        angles=[] # Initialise empty list
        next(reader) # Skip header line
        for row in reader:
                angle = float(row[0]) 
                angles.append(angle)

bins_number = 18  # the [-180, 180) interval will be subdivided into this
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, bins_number + 1)

n, _, _ = plt.hist(angles, bins) # Create histogram
plt.show()

# Create circular histogram

plt.clf()
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n, width=width, bottom=10.0, align='edge', color='red')
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

**Example rostral.csv values:**

```
1.214109733,2.678066227
1.214109733,2.378408071
1.214109733,2.378408071
1.290159115,2.314906
1.193219453,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
-1.7325846,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.208196994,2.314906
1.248951138,2.314906
0.945157766,2.314906
-1.343997479,2.314906
-1.561624822,2.314906
-1.903895159,2.314906
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a few lines from `radians.csv` (as text) ? That way we could copy/paste it and recreate your problem.

Comment: Example rostral.csv values have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your second set of angles at the same time as reading the first column. All of the data could then be displayed using subplots to give you a 2 by 2 layout of all of the graphs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

angles1 = []
angles2 = []

with open('radians.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # Skip header line

    for row in reader:
        angles1.append(float(row[0]))
        angles2.append(float(row[1]))


bins_number = 18  # the [-180, 180) interval will be subdivided into this
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, bins_number + 1)

ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
n1, _, _ = plt.hist(angles1, bins) # Create histogram
ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
n2, _, _ = plt.hist(angles2, bins) # Create histogram

# Create circular histograms
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1, projection='polar')
bars1 = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n1, width=width, bottom=10.0, align='edge', color='red', alpha=0.5)
ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3, projection='polar')
bars2 = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n2, width=width, bottom=10.0, align='edge', color='red', alpha=0.5)

plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
plt.show()
```

This would give you a graph looking like:

[image: matplot figure]

---

The plots could be combined as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

angles1 = []
angles2 = []

with open('radians.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # Skip header line

    for row in reader:
        angles1.append(float(row[0]))
        angles2.append(float(row[1]))


bins_number = 18  # the [-180, 180) interval will be subdivided into this
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, bins_number + 1)

ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
n1, _, _ = plt.hist(angles1, bins, color='red') # Create histogram
n2, _, _ = plt.hist(angles2, bins, color='blue') # Create histogram

# Create circular histograms
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='polar')
bars1 = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n1, width=width, bottom=10.0, align='edge', color='red', alpha=0.5)
bars2 = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n2, width=width, bottom=10.0, align='edge', color='blue', alpha=0.5)

plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
plt.show()
```

Giving the combined output as:

[image: matplot output - combined graphs]

Comment: Great! What would I change to get both sets of radians on the same histogram/circular histogram?

Comment: I have added an example showing how this could be done.

Comment: Thanks again! When I run this on uneven data (fewer measurements at the 1st index) I get a "ValueError: could not convert string to float" at line 13. Any idea why this is happening?